# Iterate over base classes and variadic parameter list

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

Let's say I have a following structure with a method `fun`.

```
template<class T, template <class> class ... base_t>
struct S : base_t<T> ... {
    template<class ... args_t>
    void fun(args_t& ... args) {
        //Here
    }
};
```

What I want to do in `//Here` is to assign the result of calling the `operator()()` of n–th base to the n-th argument. That means if I have two structures like that:

```
template<class>
struct D1 {
    double operator()() { return 4.2; }
};
template<class>
struct D2 {
    double operator()() { return 4.2; }
};
template<class>
struct I {
    int operator()() { return 42; }
};
```

Then this code should print `4.2 4.2 42`:

```
S<double, D1, D2, I> s;
double a, b;
int c;
s.fun(a, b, c);
std::cout << a << ' ' << b << ' ' << c << std::endl;
```

Comment: I'm not yet getting the first code, that looks like inheriting from template<> classes.

Comment: And you example of using it doesn’t work with since `D` and `I` aren’t any kind of template.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I rewrote my code and a made a few mistakes, it should be ok now.

Comment: It still does not. I think the only needed changes are putting `class` before the `... base_t`, and putting semicolons after the definitions of `struct`s `D` and `I`.

Comment: @KamilKoczurek Oh, and you can’t have duplicate base types at all. Why are you even bothering to inherit from these bases?

Comment: @DanielH Sorry, I apparently can't really write code without mistakes if I don't compile it. ;-; And it's just a minimal example, I obviously wouldn't go for inheritance in that case.

Comment: @KamilKoczurek Fair enough, but you should put your minimal example in a compiler. Your class template parameter list is [still invalid](https://godbolt.org/g/qE6PiK).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++17, with fold expression:

```
template <typename ... base_t>
struct S : base_t ... {
    template<typename ... args_t>
    void fun(args_t& ... args) {
        (base_t::operator()(args), ...);
    }
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3070c08f03098847)

Comment: Since the `operator()`s don’t take arguments and instead return the results, this’ll need to be `args = base_t::operator()()`, which needs to be wrapped in an extra set of parentheses to remove the potential for apparent ambiguity in the fold expression.

Comment: @DanielH: In that case, I would do `std::tie(args...) = std::forward_as_tuple(base_t::operator()()...);`.